# Is there a short way to subtract rows within the same column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the unemployment levels of Austria between 2006 and 2012. I would like to subtract the unemployment of each year with the year 2008 as a first step. Second i would like also to subtract the unemployment of each year with the average of the first three years combined (2006, 2007, 2008). Is there an elegant way and a short way to do it?

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(cntry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "Austria", class = "factor"), unemp = c(5.2, 4.9, 
4.1, 5.3, 4.8, 4.6, 4.9), year = 2006:2012), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), groups = structure(list(cntry = structure(1L, .Label = "Austria", class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:7), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possibility using `dplyr`:

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(
    unemp2 = unemp - unemp[year == 2008],
    unemp3 = unemp - mean(unemp[1:3])
    )

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   cntry [1]
  cntry   unemp  year unemp2  unemp3
  <fct>   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Austria   5.2  2006    1.1  0.467 
2 Austria   4.9  2007    0.8  0.167 
3 Austria   4.1  2008    0   -0.633 
4 Austria   5.3  2009    1.2  0.567 
5 Austria   4.8  2010    0.7  0.0667
6 Austria   4.6  2011    0.5 -0.133 
7 Austria   4.9  2012    0.8  0.167
```

The column `unemp2` is unemployment rate minus the unemployment rate of the year 2008.

The column `unemp3` is the unemployment rate minus the average unemployment rate of the first three years.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try, close to **@Cettt**:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- data %>% mutate(v2008=unemp-unemp[year==2008],
                v3years=unemp-mean(unemp[year%in%c(2006,2007,2008)]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   cntry [1]
  cntry   unemp  year v2008 v3years
  <fct>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Austria   5.2  2006   1.1  0.467 
2 Austria   4.9  2007   0.8  0.167 
3 Austria   4.1  2008   0   -0.633 
4 Austria   5.3  2009   1.2  0.567 
5 Austria   4.8  2010   0.7  0.0667
6 Austria   4.6  2011   0.5 -0.133 
7 Austria   4.9  2012   0.8  0.167
```

Answer (score 1):

Using basic R (no idea about the elagance)

Create a variable for the reference year:

```
ref_year<-2008
```

Step 1

```
df$unemp-df[which(df$year==ref_year),"unemp"]
[1] 1.1 0.8 0.0 1.2 0.7 0.5 0.8
```

Step 2

```
df$unemp-mean(df[c(1:3),"unemp"])
[1]  0.46666667  0.16666667 -0.63333333  0.56666667  0.06666667 -0.13333333  0.16666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, `:=`(v1 = unemp - unemp[year == 2008], v2 = unemp - mean(first(unemp, 3)))]
```

such that

```
> df
     cntry unemp year  v1          v2
1: Austria   5.2 2006 1.1  0.46666667
2: Austria   4.9 2007 0.8  0.16666667
3: Austria   4.1 2008 0.0 -0.63333333
4: Austria   5.3 2009 1.2  0.56666667
5: Austria   4.8 2010 0.7  0.06666667
6: Austria   4.6 2011 0.5 -0.13333333
7: Austria   4.9 2012 0.8  0.16666667
```